# Вывести максимальную зарплату в каждом городе

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть запрос в котором нужно вывести максимальную зарплату в каждом городе, причем сотрудники и города находятся в разных таблицах.

Собственно сами таблицы:

[image: Таблица с сотрудниками]

[image: Таблица с городами]

У меня были попытки написать запрос но в запросе чего то не хватает, не могу понять чего.

```
select ename,deptno, sal 
from (
    select ename, deptno, sal, rank() over(partition by deptno order by sal desc) n_rank 
    from emp natural join (select distinct loc, deptno from dept)) 
where n_rank = 1;
```

А проблема в том что не могу вместо `deptno` вывести название города.

Comment: _Собственно сами таблицы_, это не таблицы. это картинки.

Comment: превдокод `select *, ( select max(salary) from people where people.city=cities.city ) from cities` ?

Answer (score 2):

Вот так пoлучить список всех сотрудников, получающих топовый заработок в своём городе:

```
select ename, city, salary 
from (
    select first_name||' '||last_name ename, l.city, salary,
        max (salary) keep (
            dense_rank first order by e.salary) over (partition by city) sitytopsal
    from hr.employees e
    join hr.departments d on d.department_id = e.department_id
    join hr.locations l on l.location_id = d.location_id
) where salary = sitytopsal order by salary desc
/
```

Результат:

```
ENAME            CITY                         SALARY
---------------- ------------------------ ----------
Hermann Baer     Munich                        10000
Susan Mavris     London                         6500
Sundita Kumar    Oxford                         6100
Pat Fay          Toronto                        6000
Diana Lorentz    Southlake                      4200
Karen Colmenares Seattle                        2500
TJ Olson         South San Francisco            2100
```

PS В примере использована стандартная схема примеров [HR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/comsc/schema-diagrams.html#GUID-01BFEF14-C6BD-42CD-8558-DDD214DB3AE0).

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно просто вывести город и максимальную зарплату в нём, используйте обычную группировку:

```
 select LOC, max(SAL) as MAX_SALARY
 from emp 
 inner join dept on dept.DEPTNO = emp.DEPTNO
 group by LOC
```

Если нужно вывести данные по каждому сотруднику и в дополнение указать, какая максимальная зп в его городе, можно использовать такой вариант:

```
select 
  e.ename, 
  e.deptno,  
  e.sal, 
  d.loc, 
  max(e.sal) over(partition by loc) as max_salary
from emp e 
inner join dept d on   d.deptno = e.deptno;
```

Comment: А если надо в каждом городе максимальную зарплату с именем человека с такой зарплатой, не получается именно состыковать LOC, ENAME,MAX(SAl)